# How to give command to command promt from a PHP file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, command-prompt

I am making an online judge. It is a school project. I am using CodeIgniter. I am also using xampp. Now I need to give a command to the command prompt from my controller. I have tried using the system function and the exec function, but it still isn't working. My code was

```
    exec('my command');
    system('my command');
```

These are not working. Am I using then correctly or is there a problem with the argument?

Comment: Why not use `mkdir()`? http://php.net/mkdir

Comment: making a directory isn't my objective. I need to do something else with the system. This was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and as already mentioned: Use [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) for creating directories.

Second: What is `md` supposed to do? The command here is `mkdir`, too. And thirdly, considering `exec`, take a look at the `exec` function:

`string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`

So what you can do (if you want to stick to `exec` for whatever reason or for future use cases):

```
exec("your command", $output, $return_var);
echo "returned with " . $return_var;
print_r($output);
```

This will tell you what went wrong with your command execution.

Comment: again, I am sorry for the confusion but making a directory isn't my objective. The objective is to give a command to the command prompt.